# prevent child component render before my parent controller resolve the data

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-render

My situation

I have an `app.module`, wich bootstrap app.component

and the router
***base href = '/'***

which loads my home.component

where i have method onInit()
where i getting my data from the api using **RiotService**

`this.riot.Summoner.byName(this.summoner, this.region);`

so i can do like

```
this.riot.Summoner.byName(this.summoner, this.region).then(()=> {
   //do something with data
   //this.riot.Summoner.info
});
```

### Next step

I have my summoner.component
and it has its own route ***'/summonerName/etc'***
where i need to use data retrieved from parent component (home.component)

Its okay when i go first to ***'/'***, then to ***'/summonerName/etc'*** using `[routerLink]` for example

but when i go directly to ***'/summonerName/etc'*** or refresh the page

my home.component starts to retrieve data from my `RiotServive` and when i try to get `this.riot.Summoner.info` i get `undefined` when my `summoner.component` got rendered.

I know its all because of my promise resolving a bit longer than child component rendering.

So i have a question.

**How can i prevent my child component render before my parent controller resolve the data**

Here is my RiotService

```
request<T>(url:string, errorHandler?: (error: any) => Promise<any>){
    return this.http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json() as T)
        .catch(errorHandler || this.handleError);
}
byName(summonerName:string, region:string){
    return this.request<ISummoner>(
            `some url to get data`)
        .then((response) => {
            this.info = response as ISummoner
        })
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into resolves? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Comment: nice! It Works! Thx

Answer (score -1):

Simply use [`Resolvers`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html), it will make sure data is loaded before a route is actually activated.

The following article explain the idea with a step by step examples

> https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html